# Target class doesn't exist in Backpack on Linux

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

On my Windows localhost app, everything works well.

However, since I deployed my app to Linux, I get this error: `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserCrudController] does not exist.`

If I remove the routes, everything works well.

I tried the answers I saw but it didn't work.

I checked my routes and everything seems fine:

```
<?php

// --------------------------
// Custom Backpack Routes
// --------------------------
// This route file is loaded automatically by Backpack\Base.
// Routes you generate using Backpack\Generators will be placed here.

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ValidationController;

Route::group(['middleware' => [config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web')]], function () {
    Route::get('admin/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('backpack.auth.register');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\RegisterController@register');
});

Route::group([
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => array_merge(
        (array) config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web'),
        (array) config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')
    ),
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () { // custom admin routes
    Route::crud('user', 'UserCrudController');
    Route::crud('business-type', 'BusinessTypeCrudController');
    Route::crud('document-type', 'DocumentTypeCrudController');
    Route::crud('offered-service', 'OfferedServiceCrudController');
    Route::crud('animal', 'AnimalCrudController');
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'validation'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [ValidationController::class, 'index']);
        Route::get('/{company}/show', [ValidationController::class, 'show']);
    });
    Route::crud('company', 'CompanyCrudController');
    Route::crud('branch', 'BranchCrudController');
}); // this should be the absolute last line of this file
```

Same thing for my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class UserCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class UserCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\User::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/user');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('user', 'users');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('first_name');
        CRUD::column('last_name');
        CRUD::column('email');
        CRUD::column('password');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(UserRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('first_name');
        CRUD::field('last_name');
        CRUD::field('email');
        CRUD::field('password');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']));
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: what is the filename of that `UserCrudController` class and where is it located?

Comment: @lagbox It's UserCrudController.php and located in app/Http/Controllers/admin

Comment: @lagbox I feel so stupid, that was the error! You can post as an answer please?

Comment: its because of linux file system issue. Linux file name is case sensitive. that's why you should name and find out file with exact same name along with exact namespace

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an issue about case sensitivity. In linux `Directoryname/` is not same as `directoryname/`
first a solution could be  make git on your server to ignore case, this is so that once you rename the files are considered the same. and do not need a remove and read.
Then in future ensure paths to your controllers always start with an uppercase.